# Console getting .text() each time content changed on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

There is a page that changes its content every time a button clicked(It doesn't fully load again just a part). I want to get get its content every time content changed. When I use this code on javascript console:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){$(".SentenceContent").text(); $("#NextContent").click();}
```

It returns the  with NextContent instead of SentenceContent's text.

So the question is how can I get SentenceContent's text each time the NextContent clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The change event will never fire for that div. Instead you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
$('.SentenceContent').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
  var text = $(this).html();
  console.log(text);
});
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/pvVOWb?editors=101)